# Where are Keyboard Shortcuts stored?

Tags: backup, settings, restore, shortcut-keys

I would like to *not* copy all settings from my previous Ubuntu install, but I would like to restore my keyboard shortcuts.

Are these shortcuts stored in some hidden folder in my home folder, and if so which?

I would like to restore as few other settings along with them as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything is inside the `.gconf` folder in your home directory

You can run the following command to see which files in that directory contain information about your keybindings:

```
$~ ls -aR | grep 'gconf.*keybindings'
```

However, you should **ALWAYS** search before posting, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26056/where-are-gnome-keyboard-shortcuts-stored) is the same as yours as far as I can tell, and has some good answers.