# How to backup/restore system custom keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: backup, shortcuts, restore

Is it possible to backup the custom keyboard shortcuts and restore them when doing a fresh install?

Comment: I also have the same question. I took the privilege to rephrase your question.

Comment: Those are likely stored in .dconf. You can export and import those through `gsettings`. It is best to save the "setting" of these as a command. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal for example; all you need to find is the one you edited ;)

Comment: How did you configure your keyboard shortcuts? Through the systems settings application or are you using custom-crafted XKB hooks?

Comment: @DavidFoerster yes through the systems settings (in my case I'm using Ubuntu Gnome)

Comment: A relevant answer has [a Perl script that exports & imports shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/a/217310/110181). The script works but it didn't save my custom shortcuts.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Gnome-Control-Center (used by Unity and Gnome Shell) stores its key bindings in the per-user Dconf database directories `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/` and `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/` ([source](//wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings)).

- The easiest way to keep them across system re-installations is to keep the per-user configuration directories (`~/.config` or more specifically `~/.config/dconf/user` for Dconf only). Most of the time it's not necessary or desirable to purge the per-user configuration files anyway.
- If you can't or won't keep your old Dconf database you can use the `dconf` command to export (“dump”) parts of it into a file and import (“load”) it later. The relevant Dconf directories are

  - `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/` for pre-defined shortcuts and
  - `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/` for custom, user-defined shortcuts.

  The following example saves the above Dconf directories  to two files `keybindings.dconf` and `custom-keybindings.dconf` and then restores them from the same files:

  ```sh
  dconf dump '/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/' > keybindings.dconf
  dconf dump '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/' > custom-keybindings.dconf

  dconf load '/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/' < keybindings.dconf
  dconf load '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/' < custom-keybindings.dconf
  ```

If you find that you export your keybindings often, it might be convenient to [script the required steps](https://gist.github.com/peterrus/e59a96688a4d49ee3d9302c0d3ff5fdd).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I moved the user file to user.bk and my custom shortcuts still work (needs a reboot because a new file was created & seems to restore my preferences?)
Also for `dconf` that directory (/org) doesn't exist

Comment: Where did you get the idea that there's no `/org/` directory in the Dconf database? Both Unity and Gnome wouldn't work very well without it.

Comment: Because I tried `cd`ing into it & your command saves an empty file

Comment: You can't “change the working directory” to be a Dconf database directory because they're not part of a file system. Instead they are key prefixes in a hierarchical key-value store. Yes, the Dconf database is stored as a file but its contents aren't files.

Comment: For custom bindings, the path is `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/`. I'm on Debian Buster running Gnome 3.30.2.