# Where does Ubuntu Gnome store the keyboard shortcuts configuration file?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am looking to copy the keyboard shortcuts file to another PC to avoid re-binding the keys again. I am using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

In Xubuntu there is a simple location with the keyboard shortcuts in a file in *~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml*.  You can copy and paste this file to another computer, and you have all your familiar keyboard shortcuts. Is there an equivalent file in Ubuntu Gnome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**GNOME** stores its settings in the ***dconf*** binary database which can also be viewed or changed with the `gsettings` command line tool or the `dconf-editor` app.

The database is stored in `~/.config/dconf/user` . You can copy that file to another computer to copy all of your GNOME settings including your keyboard shortcuts. That folder is hidden by default. Use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to view hidden folders.

Other apps store their settings in other parts of the `~/.config` folder or directory.

Answer (score 4):

Also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560567/209677).

### Save custom keyboard shortcuts

You can save/backup/export custom shortcuts/keybindings using just [`dconf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dconf.1.html) and `sed`

#### Export

```sh
dconf dump / | sed -n '/\[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys/,/^$/p' > custom-shortcuts.conf # Export
```

The difference with the usual answer is that this will hold on the file the path to the dconf settings, making it easier to import, just `dconf load / < file`.

#### Import

```sh
dconf load / < custom-shortcuts.conf # Import
```

#### Notes

- Based on [Ciro's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/746262/349837) (also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1093110/349837))
- Only for the *added* custom shortcuts
- Note that `dconf` only dumps non-default values
- To backup, you may want to use `custom-shortcuts-$(date -I).conf`
- Test if it works by [resetting to defaults](https://askubuntu.com/a/315226/349837) before the import

  ```
  gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
  ```