# Where is config file for Keyboard shortcuts kept for 20.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Where is config file for Keyboard shortcuts kept for 20.04?

[image]

I want to copy it to another Ubuntu installation.

I saw this, but nothing helped.

[Where does Ubuntu Gnome store the keyboard shortcuts configuration file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787451/where-does-ubuntu-gnome-store-the-keyboard-shortcuts-configuration-file)

Doing this resulted in an empty file.

```
dconf dump / | sed -n '/\[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys/,/^$/p' > custom-shortcuts.conf # Export
```

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787451/where-does-ubuntu-gnome-store-the-keyboard-shortcuts-configuration-file) answer your question? I added a new answer, based on my answer on Unix SE.

Comment: @Pablo Bianchi I edited the question.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Which desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu Mate. I believe it's desktop is Gnome shell. As my post states, I want to have the same keyboard shortcuts on another installation. @Pablo Bianchi

Comment: I am trying a new idea. Make a change in keyboard shortcuts and see which files have changed. This finds too many files. cd /
find . -daystart -type f -mtime 0 -ls