# Shift+Alt+Down does not work as Shortcut for PHPStorm or any other app Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

Ubuntu 18.04.01 upgraded from 16.04

Shift Alt Down does not work in PHPStorm. Also, I can't assign any shortcut to it and it is not recognized as a shortcut (but top, left, and right do get recognized.

I use PHPStorm and cannot do a Move Line Down because of this.

```
cat /etc/default/keyboard
XKBLAYOUT=us
XKBVARIANT=intl
BACKSPACE=guess
```

[image]

EDI: I have reinstalled the OS (18.04.1) just to ensure it wasn't a problem with updating. BUT I kept my home folder. It doesn't work either. But my Gnome extensions are there, so maybe there is a config directory for it in my home folder? Previous to reinstall, I renamed the folders gconf, gnome and compiz in the home folder.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show us the output of the command `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson done

Comment: Ok, the explanation is not there. What about the output from this command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson `@as []`

Comment: Thanks. My theory was that Alt+Shift had been silently enabled as a shortcut for changing input language, and thus prevented the shortcuts you mention to work properly. Now we know that's not the case. So we are back at square one. Hopefully someone else is able to help.

Comment: it works in VScode, after editing `keybindings.json` file for custom shortcuts. also you can cutomize color theme and shortcuts settings same as of PHPstorm in vscode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I certainly don't know the exact answer of why this happened or what is the related config.

I saw that with a new user, this problem and the Super L to lock not working, were solved.

So I tried copying the `.config` directory of the new user, but it didn't work. Then I copied all the files and directories beginning with a dot (hidden) including the `.profiles` and it worked. I lost all the configs, but it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

Try a basic keyboard configuration. In my 16.04 and 18.04 it is setup like this:

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS=""

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

---

There is a bug report: [Unable to use  shortcuts with  keyboard layout switcher on Ubuntu MATE, 16.04 (with HWE), 17.10 and 18.04 LTS](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/marco/+bug/1720364)

Unfortunately the bug report has no fix yet.

---

Fortunately there is a solution that might work posted by Norbert in another forum: [Keyboard layout switching problems and poll](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Please read both links thoroughly before proceeding.

Comment: Hi, it didn't fix my poblem. I do NOT have a problem switching keyboards, my problem is just that I cannot assign ALT SHIFT ARROWDOWN as a shortcut. (And while it is set as a shortcut in PHPStorm, from previous setup, it does not work).
In Ubuntu Settings, Devices, Keyboard, Add new shortcut, ALT SHIFT ARROWDOWN does not get recognized. But ALT SHIFT ARROWUP for example, does.

Comment: @JorgeeFG Sorry to hear that. I've added one more thing to try at the top of the answer. If that doesn't help I'll delete my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have 18.04? Can you assign the shortcut I named? Because if you can, maybe it is some config remaining in my home directory. Although I could try with a new user I guess

Comment: Indeed it does work, same as Super L to lock. What should I delete in my home directory?

Comment: @JorgeeFG Keyboard shortcuts are not stored in one place: https://askubuntu.com/questions/26056/where-are-gnome-keyboard-shortcuts-stored

Comment: Thanks, I got tired of this, so I just copied all the files and directories beginning with a dot and it worked, though I lost many configs.

Comment: @JorgeeFG I've reinstalled apps and configs from scratch many times so I know how that feels. Glad it's working now though.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because most probably Alt + Shift switches input language for you and it doesn't let PHPStorm use that shortcut. Bad bad gnome.