# Restore default keyboard shortcut for Workspace Switcher/Show Desktop

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, window

I tried setting the default keyboard shortcut to **Hide normal windows** (Show desktop) to 
<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

It didn't work and now whenever I press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, I get the workspace switcher. I tried setting **Hide normal windows** back to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, but it doesn't work. I'm still getting the Workspace switcher.

How can I reset these two settings? I use the Show Desktop quite a lot and it is quite annoying not being able to do it.

Comment: Are you using 12.10?  'Ctrl' + 'Super' +'S' doesn't do anything for me.  I use 'Ctrl' + 'Super' + 'D'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue simply by setting **Hide normal windows** to the original <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

As somebody else told me, the shortcut for Workspace switcher is not customisable.

However I think I discovered a bug: setting <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for **Hide normal windows** actually sets it for **Workspace switcher**. Would like to report this bug but don't know which package is responsible for this behavior.