# How can I restore default keyboard shortcuts in 12.10?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, shortcuts

This question has been asked [already](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17626/how-can-i-restore-default-keyboard-shortcuts), but it doesn't seem to apply to Ubuntu 12.10. The file formats of `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings/` has changed.

I tried the script someone kindly provided...

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings
for entry in $(grep KeyListEntry * |cut -d'/' -f2- |cut -d'"' -f1); do
    echo $entry
    gconftool -u "/$entry"
done
```

But it returns...

> Error unsetting '/KeyListEntry>': Bad key or directory name:
>   "/KeyListEntry>": '>' is an invalid character in key/directory names

...for every entry.

---

I changed a few of the keyboard shortcuts thinking it would only apply to my bluetooth keyboard, but I was wrong.

How can I go about resetting them in Ubuntu 12.10?

Some items like, Monitor Brightness Down, do not appear in Keyboard Settings 'Shortcuts', which is why I am looking for a reset.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Boot the Live CD

**2.** When you get to the desktop, go to Keyboard shortcuts (type `gnome-control-center keyboard` and go to shortcuts tab)

**3.** Write down the shortcuts you want to restore (don't forget to label them so you know what they are for!).

**4.** Shut down the Live CD

**5.** Boot-up Ubuntu normally

**6.** type `gnome-control-center keyboard` again and go to shortcuts tab and edit the shortcuts...

**7.** Repeat step 6 for all shortcuts you wish to change back.

Also you can copy the folder `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings/` from the live CD to a USB or something and replace the folder you have in Ubuntu.

**EDIT:** I uploaded that [folder](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24275350/keybindings.zip) for you, it's in zip so unzip it and paste it in `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/` (replace the current) I didn't edit any shortcuts.

Comment: I tried copying/moving your unzipped folder via terminal, and it kept reporting 'Device or resource busy'. I even tried via the live CD. I have not tried manually editing the shortcuts as you mention, because I am unsure which ones have changed.

Comment: Type `lsof +D /usr/share/gnome-control-center/` and then kill the process that is using it or just do that in recovery mode.

Comment: Thanks, but that command seems wrong. Running `lsof +D -V /usr/share/gnome-control-center/` tells me _lsof: +d not followed by a directory path_. So instead I run `lsof -V /usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings/` and that tells me _lsof: no file use located: /usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings/_. I tested the output by pretending to edit one of the files to see if it noticed, and it did. This also happened via recovery mode (root shell). So in summary, I still do not know why it is stating 'Device or resource busy'