# Cannot switch workspace with shortcuts

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces

In Ubuntu 16.04 I had to reboot and after logging in there was no GUI, just the background color of my desktop and mouse. I could not open any applications except System Monitor. I tried to end a couple of processes related to unity in the hope that menu etc. would shop up again. No luck, so I did a shutdown with the power button.

After reboot, everything seemed to be OK, except that I couldn't switch workspace with shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd>) - so, that's my problem now.

I tried:

- Changing the shortcuts in keyboard settings
- unity --reset
- gsettings reset-recursively (different stuff) [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17626/how-can-i-restore-default-keyboard-shortcuts#315226)
- reboot

Other shortcuts related aren't working either, like Super+Home to switch to Workspace 1. I can switch using Super+S. When I pull up the shortcut list holding Super down 2 sec. I can see that the shortcut for switching (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Cursor Keys</kbd>) are not mentioned... Other shortcuts seem to work. Using the mouse to snap a window to the maximum are not working either (double-click works).

Maybe I stopped something that didn't start again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer myself using this guide: [How To Reset Unity And Compiz In Ubuntu 14.04, 13.10 Or 13.04](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html).

Installed dconf-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Did the reset:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

And restart Unity:

```
setsid unity
```

And then I rebooted just to be sure.

Finally, you need to re-enable workspaces after the reboot.