# Switch Workspace Shortcut Broken

Tags: 16.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Ubuntu 16.04. LTS, Unity

After the last update, I cannot switch workspaces with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Key</kbd> nor move windows with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Key</kbd>.

This answer here didn't help: [Cannot switch workspace with shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832550/cannot-switch-workspace-with-shortcuts)

I tried: Setting the shortcuts in the menu, setting the shortcuts in dconf Editor & rebooting.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and [this reference](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1627472) worked for me. You have to install `ccsm` (*compizconfig-settings-manager*) tool:

`sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra`

open it:

`ccsm`

and you have to click the *Desktop Wall* option under the *Desktop* tab on the left panel.

[image: See this image]

I hope it helps you too.