# How can I restore default keyboard shortcuts in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys

I accidentally changed two shortcuts under **Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers** It was the **Search** and **Launch help Browser** shortcuts.

I don't know what the defaults were for those two and I want to restore them.

Comment: On my computer there are no shortcuts for **Search** or **Launch help Browser**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I restore default keyboard shortcuts?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17626/how-can-i-restore-default-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

Install and run `dconf-editor`:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Look for these settings to restore defaults:

```
/org/compiz/integrated/show-hud
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/window-screenshot
```