# Why do keyboard shortcuts stop working in Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome

Tags: gnome, 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I just updated from Ubuntu 16.04 Unity to Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME. The update went well except for one thing: some times IntelliJ Ultimate keyboard shortcuts simply stop working. They work for some time and then they stop. I have only 2 GNOME extensions enabled: Ubuntu Dock and User Themes.

What can be the cause? How can I troubleshoot this?

If I restart IntelliJ they start working again, but eventually stop working.

All the keyboard shortcuts are affected:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (to open settings in IntelliJ)
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to move back and forward in the code.
- All shortcut keys.
- Arrow keys don't even work to move up and down in the code.

Comment: Too broad. Which exact shortcuts are broken?

Comment: All... Ctrl + Shift + A (to open settings in IntelliJ), Shift + Alt + Left/Right to move back and forward in the code. All shortcut keys. Arrows in the code don't even work like up or down.

Comment: I hava the some problem with eclipse, look like the combination Shift+Ctrl+XXX not working, may be caused of IME?

Comment: On "Settings> Devices> Keyboard" all my custom shortcuts that use `xdotool` like `xdotool key XF86AudioNext` stop working because also on terminal won't work. I wonder if this is related to some other shortcuts on "Sound and Media" stop working also. [Maybe one of this bugs](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&search=shortcut)?. Worth taking a look to `dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/ | grep -v disabled`.

Comment: Upgrading always can have some glitches. You may want to reinstall fresh.

Comment: To be sure, have you tried another keyboard? I think it was a logitech, when I went from 14 to 16, it had problems with any multiple combination of short cut keys. Another keyboard and it worked again.

Comment: First Check in settings If the Option for Keyboard shortcut is turned on. Try to reinstall the Softwares which you downloaded recently and has some stuff related to keyboard (Extensions sometimes create problem).

Comment: Could also try to [reset all keyboard shortcuts to default](https://askubuntu.com/a/315226/349837)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really have great insights into this problem, but rather than leaving it without any answers, I'll share what I have. I think the comments on the question are great. Given that the problem happens after some time elapses running IntelliJ, I would suspect that some other application starts running and grabs those shortcut keys. It might even be some sort of plug-in in IntelliJ.

You might investigate any recently started processes when you first notice the problem start happening, via

```bsh
ps e -o pid,start_time,command --sort start_time
```

If it is a transient process, that could be harder.