# how to reset/restor my keboard setting to the original setting?

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, logitech

Im using Ubuntu 16.04.
I messed up my keyboard setting when I was trying to add my media keys.
I added a couple of ppa and remove also some.
blindly copied and pasted commands from the net.
Now, time to time my keyboard does not work, I have to turn it on and off to start working again.
Is there any way to fix it? Can I bring its setting back to normal?

Comment: It would help to know the sites you visited for instructions. Type "Ubuntu media keys" into google search and hopefully those sites will show up in a different color.

Answer (score 0):

Do it one by one. [(Source).](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17626/how-can-i-restore-default-keyboard-shortcuts)

1. Go to Settings. (On terminal type `gnome-control-center` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> )
2. Click Devices in the sidebar.
3. Click Keyboard in the sidebar to open the panel.
4. Click the row for the desired action. The Set shortcut window will be shown.
5. Hold down the desired key combination, or press Backspace to reset, or press Esc to cancel.

or try the command

```
gsettings reset-recursively  org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

Comment: does it work for ubuntu 16.04?